# How to block access to /register only for anon. and redirect others to other page?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I tried to use:

```
- { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

in access_control in my security.yml but it doesn't work.
I can still be logged in and use /register page.
The goal is to redirect logged users to /account and show message ("Please logout before you try to register new account.").

Kind regards,
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of role hierarchy, logged in user also have role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`. Solution is:

```
 - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICADED_FULLY }
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. How to solve the rest of my question (redirection with message)?